# TensorFlow install

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

After install tensorflow package and import tensorflow as tf I get this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/y0/fgmyd4_n40v7cyffpx8hm5480000gn/T/ipykernel_75240/3793406994.py in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>
     44 
     45 # Bring in subpackages.
---> 46 from tensorflow.python import data
     47 from tensorflow.python import distribute
     48 # from tensorflow.python import keras

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/__init__.py in <module>
     23 
     24 # pylint: disable=unused-import
---> 25 from tensorflow.python.data import experimental
     26 from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops import AUTOTUNE
     27 from tensorflow.python.data.ops.dataset_ops import Dataset



/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/service/__init__.py in <module>
    372 from __future__ import print_function
    373 
--> 374 from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.data_service_ops import distribute
    375 from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.data_service_ops import from_dataset_id
    376 from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.data_service_ops import register_dataset

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/compression_ops.py in <module>
     18 from __future__ import print_function
     19 
---> 20 from tensorflow.python.data.util import structure
     21 from tensorflow.python.ops import gen_experimental_dataset_ops as ged_ops
     22 



/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py in <module>
     31 from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import tf_export
     32 
---> 33 _np_bfloat16 = _pywrap_bfloat16.TF_bfloat16_type()
     34 
     35 

TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was
    () -> handle
```

I tried to uninstall TensorFlow and numpy and install again, but it didn't help

Name: numpy
Version: 1.21.6

Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.7.0

I work in macOS Monterey 12.5.1

Comment: It seems like you are trying this in an IPython notebook? Does `import tensorflow as tf` work when you open a `python3.9` REPL in a terminal?

Comment: yes, in jupyter.
if I open terminal, it shows
>>> import tensorflow as tf
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python3.9

Comment: Is this on an M1 mac? Ar you sure you are using a native version of Python and tensorflow?

Comment: it's M2. I'm not sure, i only install anaconda distributive, what means native?

Comment: Native means that the software is compiled to run on the CPU of the machine. When Apple made the latest switch from Intel (x86-64) chips to their own (arm64) chips, they built software into the OS that enables x86-64 binaries to run on their arm64 chips. This is called emulation. Unfortunately it doesn't work with libraries like tensorflow. You will need to find and install a Python and tensorflow compiled for the M2 chip in your computer.

Comment: If you start a `python3.9` REPL and run `import platform` and then `platform.platform()`, what does it report?

Comment: I created env and installed necessary libraries, and it's work)

Comment: maybe problem was in version, I don't know..

Comment: Also, there are step by step instructions mentioned in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) link to install tensorflow. You can use this document as a  reference.